# Map marker color to categorical data array in plotly.js

Tags: plotly

I am trying to replicate a plot I created with R api for plotly.
Presenting a reproducible example below.
The data is as follows

```
[{"Date":"2017-09-06","variable":"ACC","vol":1.3049,"rebased":127.8198,"Industry":"CEMENT & CEMENT PRODUCTS"},
 {"Date":"2017-09-06","variable":"AMBUJACEM","vol":1.3738,"rebased":125.163,"Industry":"CEMENT & CEMENT PRODUCTS"},
 {"Date":"2017-09-06","variable":"BPCL","vol":1.9167,"rebased":79.9571,"Industry":"ENERGY"},
 {"Date":"2017-09-06","variable":"CESC","vol":2.3585,"rebased":128.2077,"Industry":"ENERGY"},
 {"Date":"2017-09-06","variable":"COALINDIA","vol":1.854,"rebased":80.9094,"Industry":"METALS"},
 {"Date":"2017-09-06","variable":"GRASIM","vol":1.694,"rebased":118.5174,"Industry":"CEMENT & CEMENT PRODUCTS"},
 {"Date":"2017-09-06","variable":"HINDALCO","vol":2.5474,"rebased":127.1915,"Industry":"METALS"},
 {"Date":"2017-09-06","variable":"HINDPETRO","vol":2.4371,"rebased":90.3253,"Industry":"ENERGY"},
 {"Date":"2017-09-06","variable":"HINDZINC","vol":2.044,"rebased":101.6822,"Industry":"METALS"},
 {"Date":"2017-09-06","variable":"IOC","vol":2.1872,"rebased":109.6917,"Industry":"ENERGY"}]
```

The chart produced by following R code

```
plot_ly(x = ~vol, y = ~rebased) %>%
  add_markers(color = ~Industry, size = I(10)) %>%
  layout(                        
    title = paste("Risk Reward as of",plotDate), 
    xaxis = list(           
      title = "1 Month Volatility",      
      showgrid = F),       
    yaxis = list(          
      title = "Index value")     
  )
```

is like this
[image: R Code Plot]

The same plot in js looks like this
[image: JS Code Plot]

Colors are clearly not mapped to the property Industry and legends are missing.

Following is the js code in my React component

```
    let xx = [];
    let yy = [];
    let zz = [];
    this.props.stocks.map( (stock, index) => {
        xx.push(stock.vol);
        yy.push(stock.rebased);
        zz.push(stock.Industry);
        }
    )
    console.log(xx);
    console.log(zz);

    let trace1 = {
        x: xx,
        y: yy,
        mode: 'markers',
        marker: {
            size:10,
            color: zz,
        }
    };

    let data = [trace1];
    let layout = { 
                    margin: { t: 0 },
                    autosize: true ,
                    title: 'Risk Reward as of 2017-09-06',
                    xaxis: {title: '1 Month Volatility'},
                    yaxis: {title: 'Index Value'},
                }


    Plotly.plot('plot', data, layout);
```

The variable zz assigned to color above shows correct values in the log

```
(10) ["CEMENT & CEMENT PRODUCTS", "CEMENT & CEMENT PRODUCTS", "ENERGY", "ENERGY", "METALS", "CEMENT & CEMENT PRODUCTS", "METALS", "ENERGY", "METALS", "ENERGY"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R Plotly's `colors` function does not exist in JavaScript Plotly. It's a convenience function which splits your input data into multiple traces (you can see that by inspecting the JS graph returned by R).

In order to get something similar with JavaScript you would need to assign your data to different traces and then pass them to Plotly.

```js
var stocks = [{
  "Date": "2017-09-06",
  "variable": "ACC",
  "vol": 1.3049,
  "rebased": 127.8198,
  "Industry": "CEMENT & CEMENT PRODUCTS"
}, {
  "Date": "2017-09-06",
  "variable": "AMBUJACEM",
  "vol": 1.3738,
  "rebased": 125.163,
  "Industry": "CEMENT & CEMENT PRODUCTS"
}, {
  "Date": "2017-09-06",
  "variable": "BPCL",
  "vol": 1.9167,
  "rebased": 79.9571,
  "Industry": "ENERGY"
}, {
  "Date": "2017-09-06",
  "variable": "CESC",
  "vol": 2.3585,
  "rebased": 128.2077,
  "Industry": "ENERGY"
}, {
  "Date": "2017-09-06",
  "variable": "COALINDIA",
  "vol": 1.854,
  "rebased": 80.9094,
  "Industry": "METALS"
}, {
  "Date": "2017-09-06",
  "variable": "GRASIM",
  "vol": 1.694,
  "rebased": 118.5174,
  "Industry": "CEMENT & CEMENT PRODUCTS"
}, {
  "Date": "2017-09-06",
  "variable": "HINDALCO",
  "vol": 2.5474,
  "rebased": 127.1915,
  "Industry": "METALS"
}, {
  "Date": "2017-09-06",
  "variable": "HINDPETRO",
  "vol": 2.4371,
  "rebased": 90.3253,
  "Industry": "ENERGY"
}, {
  "Date": "2017-09-06",
  "variable": "HINDZINC",
  "vol": 2.044,
  "rebased": 101.6822,
  "Industry": "METALS"
}, {
  "Date": "2017-09-06",
  "variable": "IOC",
  "vol": 2.1872,
  "rebased": 109.6917,
  "Industry": "ENERGY"
}]

let traces = [];
let categories = [];

for (let i = 0; i < stocks.length; i += 1) {
    if (categories.indexOf(stocks[i].Industry) === -1) {
        traces.push({x: [],
                     y: [],
                     mode: 'markers',
                     name: stocks[i].Industry
                    });
        categories.push(stocks[i].Industry);
  } else {
        traces[categories.indexOf(stocks[i].Industry)].x.push(stocks[i].vol);
        traces[categories.indexOf(stocks[i].Industry)].y.push(stocks[i].rebased);
  }
}

Plotly.plot('plot', traces);

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js">
</script>
<div id='plot'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks much for that! This works. The else condition should not be there as it skips the first stock of each category. But it's not relevant to the problem.

I had figured the color attribute accepts numerical array and was in the process of editing this. Your solution makes it easy.

I am struggling to understand how to replicate the aesthetics mapping done in R in js. e.g. How could I now, say, map size to vol for the sake of example. Thanks

Comment: Never mind my above comment about mapping size. I figured it out. Thanks a ton for your help. Accepting the answer now